# Using SSE to mimic the standard Math.pow function

Tags: c, assembly, x86, sse, simd

I'm trying to learn how to work with `SSE` and I decided to realize a simple code that computes `n^d`, using a function that gets called by a `C` program.

Here's my `NASM` code:

```
section .data

resmsg:     db      '%d^%d = %d', 0

section .bss

section .text

extern printf


; ------------------------------------------------------------
; Function called from a c program, I only use n and d parameters but I left the others
; ------------------------------------------------------------

global main

T       equ     8
n       equ     12
d       equ     16
m       equ     20
Sid     equ     24
Sn      equ     28

main:
    ; ------------------------------------------------------------
    ; Function enter sequence
    ; ------------------------------------------------------------
    push    ebp             ; save Base Pointer
    mov     ebp, esp        ; Move Base Point to current frame
    sub     esp, 8          ; reserve space for two local vars
    push    ebx             ; save some registries (don't know if needed)
    push    esi
    push    edi

    ; ------------------------------------------------------------
    ; copy function's parameters to registries from stack
    ; ------------------------------------------------------------
    mov     eax, [ebp+T]        ; T
    mov     ebx, [ebp+n]        ; n
    mov     ecx, [ebp+d]        ; d
    mov     edx, [ebp+m]        ; m
    mov     esi, [ebp+Sid]      ; Sid
    mov     edi, [ebp+Sn]       ; Sn    
    mov     [ebp-8], ecx        ; copy ecx into one of the local vars

    ;
    ; pow is computed by doing n*n d times
    ;
    movss   xmm0, [ebp+n]   ; base
    movss   xmm1, [ebp+n]   ; another copy of the base because xmm0 will be overwritten by the result

loop:   mulss   xmm0, xmm1      ; scalar mult from sse
        dec     ecx             ; counter--
        cmp     ecx,0           ; check if counter is 0 to end loop
        jnz     loop            ; 

    ;
    ; let's store the result in eax by moving it to the stack and then copying to the registry (we use the other local var as support)
    ;
    movss   [ebp-4], xmm0       
    mov     eax, [ebp-4]

    ;
    ; Print using C's printf
    ;       
    push    eax                 ; result
    mov     ecx, [ebp-8]        ; copy the original d back since we used it as loop's counter
    push    ecx                 ; exponent
    push    ebx                 ; base
    push    resmsg              ; string format
    call    printf              ; printf call
    add     esp, 24             ; clean the stack from both our local and printf's vars

    ; ------------------------------------------------------------
    ; Function exit sequence
    ; ------------------------------------------------------------

    pop edi                     ; restore the registries
    pop esi
    pop ebx
    mov esp, ebp                ; restore the Stack Pointer
    pop ebp                     ; restore the Base Pointer
    ret                         ; get back to C program
```

Now, what I'd expect is it to print

> 4^2 = 16

but, instead, I got

> 4^2 = 0

I've spent my whole afternoon on this and I couldn't find a solution, do you have any hints?

EDIT:

Since it seems a format problem, I tried converting the data using

```
movss   [ebp-4], xmm0       
fld     dword [ebp-4]
mov     eax, dword [ebp-4]
```

instead of

```
movss   [ebp-4], xmm0       
mov     eax, [ebp-4]
```

but I got the same result.

Comment: Why not just use intrinsics ? You could have done this in a fraction of the time compared to doing it from scratch in asm, and it would be a lot more portable too.

Comment: You are loading integers without converting to float, and trying to print floats with integer format too. PS: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: BTW `dec` affects the `Z` flag, so there is no need for `cmp ecx,0`

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? I edited the question with a new addition that I used to take care of the format problems but I still got the same result as before. Is the overall code correct?

Comment: I can't see what you are doing wrong in the output, but if you are computing `4^1` you will get 16, since the multiply loop iterates once. `xmm0` should be `1` at the start of the loop.

Comment: As Jester says, you need to *convert* inputs from integer to floating-point, and output from floating-point to integer. Your current code causes the integer input to be *re-interpreted* as a floating-point number, resulting in an extremely tiny number called a denormal (on the order of 10**-42). The product of those denormals is zero. This floating-point zero is then *re-interpreted* as an integer, thus the code prints zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MOVSS` moves single precision floats (32-bit). I assume that `n` is an integer so you can't load it into a XMM register with `MOVSS`. Use `CVTSI2SS` instead. `printf` cannot process single precision floats, which would converted to doubles by the compiler. It's convenient to use `CVTSS2SI` at this point. So the code should look like:

```
...
    ;
    ; pow is computed by doing n*n d times
    ;

    cvtsi2ss xmm0, [ebp+n]      ; load integer
    sub ecx, 1                  ; first step (n^1) is done
    cvtsi2ss xmm1, [ebp+n]      ; load integer

loop:
    mulss   xmm0, xmm1          ; scalar mult from sse
    sub     ecx, 1
    jnz     loop

    cvtss2si eax, xmm0          ; result as integer

    ;
    ; Print using C's printf
    ;
    push    eax                 ; result
    mov     ecx, [ebp-8]        ; copy the original d back since we used it as loop's counter
    push    ecx                 ; exponent
    push    ebx                 ; base
    push    resmsg              ; string format
    call    printf              ; printf call
    add     esp, 16             ; clean the stack only from printf's vars
...
```

Comment: Can you please give me some kind of reference to this function? I couldn't find it when I searched for a way to convert float to int, and having a link to check before asking may be helpful.

Comment: @StepTNT: The [Intel manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) plus some Google hits ("sse integer") plus a debugger (OllyDbg) plus some trials. ;-)